# How to insert data in one table from another two tables using triggers in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have been trying to insert data in a table say admin dynamically when the data in inserted in two other tables namely table_1 and table_2 . I am able to get the desired output only for one table but not multiple tables. How can i achieve this by using triggers in oracle?

Comment: Create two triggers, one on table_1 and other on  table_2.

Comment: and apply same logic just that table name will be different

Comment: Can you please clarify your question as you want only to insert into ADMIN table when same data is inserted simultaneosly in both the underlying tables?

Answer (score 0):

create 2 triggers on 2 tables  as lalit suggested

```
    CREATE or replace TRIGGER TRG_TAB1
          BEFORE INSERT ON tab1...

... insert into admin (name) values (:new.name)
```

on the other table

```
    CREATE or replace TRIGGER TRG_TAB2
          BEFORE INSERT ON tab2...
... insert into admin (name) values (:new.name)
```

Comment: I guess table name should be different ??

Comment: OP wants it the other way, triggers on the table_1 and table_2 to insert data into admin.

Comment: @Moudiz `new.name` will fail, new should be referenced as `:new`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate **INSERT triggers**, one on `table_1` and another on `table_2` to insert the data into `admin` table.

**Trigger 1:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table_1_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_1
   FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN

   -- Insert record into admin table
   INSERT INTO admin
   ( column1,
     column2,
     column3,
     column4,
     column5 )
   VALUES
   ( :new.column1,
     :new.column2,
     :new.column3,
     :new.column4,
     :new.column5 );

END;
/
```

**Trigger 2:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table_2_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_2
   FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN

   -- Insert record into admin table
   INSERT INTO admin
   ( column1,
     column2,
     column3,
     column4,
     column5 )
   VALUES
   ( :new.column1,
     :new.column2,
     :new.column3,
     :new.column4,
     :new.column5 );

END;
/
```